# Find global min values from sub-sub-lists of different lengths

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list composed of sub-lists of different length with the following shape:

```
a = [[[-0.152, -0.171, -0.132, -0.111, -0.088],[0.565, 0.718, 0.794, 0.870, 0.947]],[[-0.1293, -0.094, -0.062, -0.030, 3.207, 0.],[1.223, 1.266, 1.309, 0.231, 1.394, 1.434]]]
```

So it's basically a main list with two sub-lists `A` and `B` (could be more) and each of those has two sub-lists `A1`, `A2` and `B1`, `B2` (the number of sub-sub-lists is always fixed to 2):

```
a = [A, B]
A = [A1, A2]
B = [B1, B2]
```

`A1`, `A2` have equal lengths `La`, as do `B1`, `B2` with length `Lb`, but these lengths are not necessarily equal, ie: `La == Lb` is not always true.

I need to obtain the global minimum between `A1` and `B1` and between `A2` and `B2` and so on if there were more sub-lists of similar shapes. Ie: if I had an extra `C` sub-list in `a` with `C = [C1, C2]`, then I'd need the global minimum between `A1, B1, C1` and `A2, B2, C2`.

In the case of the `a` list above the output would have to look like:

```
array([-0.171, 0.231])
```

I've tried several variations of `np.min(a, axis=*)` but I can't get it to return what I need. If  `La == Lb` I could use `np-min` to obtain the result I need. For example, if I remove one item from each sub-sub-list `B1` and`B2` so that `La = Lb = 5` then I can use:

```
a = [[[-0.152, -0.171, -0.132, -0.111, -0.088],[0.565, 0.718, 0.794, 0.870, 0.947]],[[-0.1293, -0.094, -0.062, -0.030, 3.207],[1.223, 1.266, 1.309, 0.231, 1.394]]]
np.min(np.min(a, axis=2) ,axis=0)
array([-0.171,  0.231])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing your data structure to make the operation simpler, through numpy arrays or Pandas, or some other format, is probably best.

But, one pure-Python way to do it is:

```
map(lambda x: min(map(min, x)), zip(*a))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with converting to numpy array of `np.float`s with vectorized np.min:

```
>>> np.vectorize(np.min)(a)
array([[-0.171 ,  0.565 ],
       [-0.1293,  0.231 ]])
```

So your result can be achieved with

```
>>> np.min(np.vectorize(np.min)(a), axis=0)
array([-0.171, 0.231])
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on my actual larger list. Instead of returning a list (or array) of only two elements (the global mins) it returns a list with two sub-lists with several elements inside. EMS's solution works with my real larger list so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: @Gabriel and what is output of `np.vectorize(np.min)(a)`

Comment: Yes, but now I think I know what the issue is. I didn't mention in my question that I could also have only _one sub-list_, ie `a = [A]`. I think this is where this answer fails.

Comment: @Gabriel you said `the number of sub-sub-lists is always fixed to 2`

Comment: Yes, the number of _sub-sub-lists_ is always fixed to 2 but not the number of _sub-lists_ that can go from 1 to a lot. Perhaps I should add this to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably go with EMS's solution but here's another way to do it for your structure

```
[min(reduce(list.__add__, x, [])) for x in zip(*a)]
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution, slightly faster than the other posted for the test data. interesting to see what is faster for the real data:

```
[min([item for sublist in x for item in sublist]) for x in zip(*a)]
```